# DataFrame.set_index no tiene efecto

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

No me funciona `set_index` en DataFrame de Pandas como indica la documentación.

Estoy utilizando:

- Pandas version 0.20.3
- Python version 3.6

Probé el ejemplo que figura en la documentación:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html

```
import numpy as np  
import pandas as pd  

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'month': [1, 4, 7, 10],  
    'year': [2012, 2014, 2013, 2014],  
    'sale':[55, 40, 84, 31]})  
print('\ndf2 dataframe de ensayo')  
print(df2)  

df2.set_index('month')  
print("\ndf2: set_index='month'")  
print("\tNo toma la columna 'month' como indice")  
print(df2)  

df3 = pd.DataFrame({  
    'year': [2012, 2014, 2013, 2014],  
    'sale':[55, 40, 84, 31]  
})  
df3.index = pd.DataFrame({'month':[1, 4, 7, 10]})  
print('\ndf3')  
print(df3)
```

La salida es:

```
df2 dataframe de ensayo  
   month  sale  year  
0      1    55  2012  
1      4    40  2014  
2      7    84  2013  
3     10    31  2014  

df2: set_index='month'  
    No toma la columna 'month' como indice  
   month  sale  year  
0      1    55  2012  
1      4    40  2014  
2      7    84  2013  
3     10    31  2014  

df3  
    sale  year  
1     55  2012  
4     40  2014  
7     84  2013  
10    31  2014
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ten en cuenta que la documentación simula el uso de un intérprete interactivo. [`pandas.dataFrame.set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) no modifica por defecto el DataFrame, sino que retorna uno nuevo con el índice correctamente modificado (este retorno es lo que muestra el intérprete interactivo).

Para modificar el DataFrame sin crear uno nuevo necesitas especificar el argumento `inplace` como `True`:

> **inplace** : boolean, default False
>
> Modify the DataFrame in place (do not create a new object)

Es decir, tu código debe ser:

```
import pandas as pd  


df2 = pd.DataFrame({'month': [1, 4, 7, 10],  
                     'year': [2012, 2014, 2013, 2014],  
                     'sale': [55, 40, 84, 31]})    
df2.set_index('month',  inplace = True)   
print(df2)
```

Su salida es la esperada:

```
        sale  year
month            
1        55  2012
4        40  2014
7        84  2013
10       31  2014
```